# Copy-pasting tag wikis

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki, plagiarism

What is the policy on copy-pasting content from other sources for tag wikis?

The tag wiki for [dynamic-view](/questions/tagged/dynamic-view) was [created](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits#suggested-edits/3691958?&_suid=138841896212907734148374924518) a few minutes ago, but the content is just copied from the [blog post](http://googleblog.blogspot.hk/2011/09/dynamic-views-seven-new-ways-to-share.html) announcing the technology.

At first I thought that the edit should be rejected as plagiarism, but the user *did* insert a link to the blog. Is a link sufficient for attribution? Even if it is, do we really want to just copy-paste content from product pages for our wikis? Especially content which is, in my opinion, a bit too "[*rah rah rah*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheering)"?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to link to [Would it be OK to paste content from Wikipedia into a popular empty tag-wiki?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79000) instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I saw that, but that questions addresses **Wikipedia** tag wikis *very specifically*. This content came from Google's blog announcing (and even trying to "sell") the technology.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183715/what-is-the-policy-on-tag-wiki-edits-that-appear-to-be-copied-from-elsewhere http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80351/make-rules-regarding-copying-tag-wiki-content-from-other-websites-more-explicit http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165379/proposed-methods-for-countering-plagiarized-text-in-tag-wikis

Comment: Thanks @random. The first link is relevant. I've opened a bounty on the second. Not sure that the third applies, though.

Answer (score 2):

As a rule, such content tends to make for poor tag wikis.  Tag wikis are there to help the reader understand when they should and should not use that tag.  Text copied from other sources very rarely has that goal, or serves that task.  It generally focuses on describing the product/technology/whatever rather than explaining when/how to use the tag, as such the most appropriate action tends to be using the rejection reason:

> This edit does not follow any of our tag wiki guidelines and is unlikely to help instruct future visitors in the appropriate use of the tag.

Comment: So what should be done now that it's created? Too late to reject it.

Comment: @secretunicorngremlins If there's something better in the past history, revert it, if not, ideally one would write a quality tag wiki to replace it.

Comment: There's no point -- there's a [better tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blogger-dynamic-views) and the other has been nuked from the single question that had it.  That single question *also* had the better tag. The user that created that tag went on an almost completely unneeded tag creation spree this morning.