# New Tag Editing

Tags: discussion, tags

I created a tag, since it did not exist in a question, and I did a search on it; quite a few results. I was going to edit the tag in to them, but I figured I should check first.

If I create a new tag, is it a bad idea to edit into every question that does not have the tag? (Maybe not every, but the "good" ones perhaps?)

Comment: "every question that does not have the tag" - that is relevant to the tag subject, you mean? :-)

Comment: @JanDvorak yes of course lol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, go ahead and apply the tag to questions where it's appropriate: where it is the topic or subject of the question. Try to avoid applying it to questions where the entity it represents is only incidental to the question.

While you're doing this, please take a moment to [make a tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214337/what-is-a-tag-wiki-how-do-i-write-a-good-one) and excerpt proposal, so that other users know what the tag is for.

Comment: Already made a tag wiki, it's pending approval :)

Comment: "Try to avoid applying it to questions where the entity the tag represents is only incidental to the question." - rationale?

Comment: @RUJordan: Excellent, thanks.

Comment: Tags should make relevant, useful categorizations, @JanDvorak. The fact that I have an iMac (all but certainly) has no bearing on my C code crashing.