# Finding useful websites (possibly outside of Stack Exchange)

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Often I want to be recommended some websites (possibly outside of Stack Exchange) to achieve my goal. They can be about PCs, cars, cooking or anything. Is there a Stack Exchange site that deals with such questions?

For instance, I want to record bird sounds. Is there a helpful website, possibly outside of Stack Exchange?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Give each site a parallel site for polling, recommendations and subjective-ish stuff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57383/give-each-site-a-parallel-site-for-polling-recommendations-and-subjective-ish-s)

Comment: If you just want useful links, consider visiting the [tag wiki page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214338/289905) for a particular tag of your interest. For example, if you’re interested in Notepad++, go to [its tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/notepad++/info), and you’ll find at least five links about Notepad++.

Answer (score 6):

There's no "website recommendations" Stack Exchange site. In general, recommendations are out of scope for SE, though there are sites for [hardware](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 4):

This is not exactly what you asked for but there are some sites on the network that cover the categories you mentioned. Two of them are already referred to in [Journeyman's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/351288/348196):

- For PC software, there is [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), or [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) (and others, depending on what exactly you need).
- For PC hardware, check out [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).
- For Cars, you might find [Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) helpful. It's not about buying cars, etc. but it could be useful nonetheless. Make sure your questions are on-topic though.
- For Cooking, there's [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

You can use those sites to find the information that you would otherwise be seeking on the sites that would be recommended to you.

Answer (score 0):

Besides [@AhmedAbdelhameed's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/351289/186472) I believe it's notable that tag-wikis of bigger site tags are a good place to look for Stack Exchange external links.

Some examples:

- Stack Overflow: [About <kbd>c++</kbd>](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info)
- Stack Overflow: [About <kbd>java</kbd>](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info)
- Stack Overflow: [About <kbd>notepad++</kbd>](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/notepad++/info)
- Software Engineering: [About <kbd>architecture</kbd>](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/architecture/info)