# tag wiki question, plus synonym request: [variable-assignment] -> [assignment]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

Today I noticed new users have been occasionally tagging [assignment](/questions/tagged/assignment) where [homework](/questions/tagged/homework) should have been. [Searching SO under this tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assignment) clearly shows it's intended to refer to variable assignment. Since the tag wiki is blank, I thought including some information there would help deter people from using it as a misnomer. I put the following as the excerpt:

> This tag refers to the concept of variable assignment. For homework assignments, use the [homework] tag.

And shamelessly copied from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_%28computer_science%29) for the full wiki:

> An assignment statement sets or re-sets the value stored in the storage location(s) denoted by a variable name. In most imperative computer programming languages, assignment statements are one of the basic statements. Common notations for the assignment operator are `=` and `:=`

The edit hasn't been approved yet but I'm wondering if these are appropriate for the tag wiki. Feel free to improve on it.

Also, I noticed another tag, [variable-assignment](/questions/tagged/variable-assignment) which I think should be a synonym of [assignment](/questions/tagged/assignment).

Comment: See posts like this one:http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79000/would-it-be-ok-to-paste-content-from-wikipedia-into-a-popular-empty-tag-wiki

Comment: @jonsca - Thanks, I added a link to the Wikipedia page to the wiki as the answers to that question suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems reasonable. I think it's better to be very literal in this case, so I set up a synonym for

[assignment](/questions/tagged/assignment) → [variable-assignment](/questions/tagged/variable-assignment)

and merged them.

So there may be some (probably terrible) homework questions questions tagged "variable assignment" now...

Comment: Thanks - I'll go search and retag those homework questions when I get a chance.